# Will you hire a loser?

Tags: interviewing, hiring

In my last interview I was asked the classical question of

> Why shoud I hire you?

My succinct response was: **"only if you like losers"**, which ended the interview quickly.

I grow up as a loser, no success at any sports, not good with girls, overweight with a BMI of 28, dropped out of college, my questions keep getting negative scores in this website. I am just curious, have you ever hired a loser guy or not, if so why did you hire?

Comment: There is a difference between a loser and a person thinking he is one. No sane person will hire the latter.

Comment: I know someone who hired a loser who knows how to keep his mouth shut. But I won't join you in your pity party. Read [Notes from the Underground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_from_Underground), you can pick it up for free or very little. By the way, the guy who hired the loser is my boss, and knowing to keep my mouth shut has helped me immensely.

Comment: @lalala makes a point. Negative thinking is something people tend to avoid, as nothing good can come from indulging oneself in it and it undermines moral.
On the other hand, knowing how to make the best out of a miserable situation, even the tiniest improvement from the worst, is something valuable you should work on. Think about the little things you do right, because there must be.
I think this question belongs more to a self-improvement tag with a rephrased title : How to improve my self-esteem.

Comment: @rath I will read that Dostoyevski's book, though I find him boring. Glad to hear that you are proud of yourself.  Frederi ROSE I think I am being realistic, though I upvoted your sincere comment.

Comment: Losers don't get interviews.

Comment: like @Jeroen said : if you define yourself as a loser, that implies that everything you do, you will intend to fail. If that definition of being realistic suits you, so be it. I would rather quote Anirudh with "Try and Fail but don't try TO fail". Focus on the little things you do right for a start and make improvements.

Comment: You achieved success at being a loser, You managed a BMI of 28, that takes hard work to be considered borderline obese that takes years to achieve, and on top of that you had great success with filing the paperwork to drop out of college. And now here you are, all by your lonesome self being successful at repelling every job you come across. That's a lot of success, if you ask me.

Comment: "Will you hire a loser?" Yes, if they're good at the job I hired them for, why should I care if they self-identify as a loser? The problem is they asked why they should hire you and you answered why they shouldn't.

Comment: Do you consider yourself to be on the autism spectrum (Aspbergers, etc.)? That you don't find your response problematic is somewhat indicative.

Comment: @DavidK I really never thought that I could be that smart, I will check thanks. Are you a doctor by the way?

Comment: @DenisSmith Why did you answer the interviewer's question that way?  Was it a joke?  Was the interview going poorly?

Comment: @MikeQ frankly it was   half joke, half truth. no it was going great, I solved the technical questions.

Comment: @DenisSmith I am not a doctor, and I'm not trying to diagnose you or anything. Having interacted with people with [Asperger Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) on this site, I've learned ([from someone with experience](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6090/april-is-autism-awareness-month)) that it often helps to be more explicit when answering about social interaction and not assume that all social norms are obvious. I just wanted to make sure we were providing answers to you in a way you would find helpful.

Comment: @David K I checked the post, some of the things apply. I got curious and did a test, I found I am 4 points below the autism, I am close but not there. Of course I thought most people here helping me, and I upvoted most of them.

Comment: Tangentially related issue: [Why it is not good to make fun of yourself at work?](/questions/116888)

Comment: @DenisSmith maybe you would benefit from seeing a counselor?

Comment: My BMI is 29.5 and I am 6'3", 110kg and yes a little fat but lots of muscle... I have discussed this with several doctors who say well its a **cr1p** index for any who have developed muscles and are relatively fit... But they use it anyway to scare some into getting off the couch...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a time and a place for self-deprecation, and responding to *"Why should I hire you?"* is pretty much never it. I'd recommend thinking of some decent answers to that one and having them to mind because you'll probably encounter that one alot.

> I grow up as a loser

So? Our past is just that, the past. It needn't define your present or future unless you choose to let it.

> no success at any sports

So? Unless your job interview is for a role playing sports it doesn't matter one jot.

> not good with girls

So? Unless your job interview is for gigolo or the starring role on *The Batchelor* it doesn't matter.

> overweight with a BMI of 28

So? Some of the best developers I've ever worked with would smash that into the weeds. You code with your brain not your belly. And what does it matter anyway - so you're overweight. If you don't like it - change it. I'm not saying it's *easy*, but let's not pretend that it isn't possible.

> dropped out of college

So?  We've all failed at things in our lives, it's what you do afterwards that makes the difference about whether you're an [Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Rimmer) or [Ace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Red_Dwarf_characters#Ace_Rimmer) Rimmer. If your field means you need a college degree then go back and try again. If at first you don't succeed and all that. If not then prove you can do it in other ways, through work experience or personal projects.

> my questions keep getting negative scores in this website

Your cumulative score is still +14 at time of writing. At the risk of getting a bit meta for the main site here; I think it's relevant to this question to point out that the one's where you're basically moaning get negative scores. Whereas the one where you showed a positive attitude and wanted to do better [got substantially upvoted](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/142856/dealing-with-stress-in-coding-interviews) and favorited 4 times (at time of writing).

I think there might be a useful lesson in that which you can apply to your job hunt approach.

> have you ever hired a loser guy or not

Yes, twice.

> if so why did you hire?

Well once was because I could see that they were actually better than they thought they were - took me a couple of years to turn them around but they were one of the best employees I've ever had. The other.. well, he was a friend. That's my only excuse really - still the worst hiring mistake I've ever made.

But that's irrelevant - because you **aren't** a loser. You've just got yourself in that weird place that humans do sometimes where it's easier to self-sabotage. I get it, sometimes it's just easier to whinge and moan rather than actually doing something to make your life better - even if that moaning is aimed at yourself. Heck, I've been there a few times myself. But it doesn't help anything. It doesn't *change* anything. Instead look for things you can do that will make yourself and your life better - because really you are worth it. Everyone is.

So if you get asked *"Why should I hire you?"* Instead of answering *"Only if like losers"* you should answer *"Only if you want someone who is always striving to do better then they have before"*

Comment: sir you are a man of wisdom, and thank you for your answer, I will strive to change for the good, and I will never be scared to make mistakes again.

Answer (score 7):

> My succinct response was: "only if you like losers", which ended the interview quickly.

Being a loser is your own choice. I would never hire people who sabotage themselves like this and I don't see a reason to. The hiring process should benefit both parties. In your case, you make sure that at least one party doesn't get any benefit.

Answer (score 6):

**Try and fail but DO NOT fail to try**

Wait and there is a transition state, Where you try to fail. : )

> I grow up as a loser, no success at any sports, not good with girls, overweight with a BMI of 28, dropped out of college

The losers are actually invariably the ones who follow the second part(fail to try). You decided to go for the interview...means you wanted to try but still stuck on the above mentioned transition state.

You can now either go left or right. Choice is yours. ;)

Comment: wow very interesting point, can you elaborate, I want to know about this more, is there any books on that?

Comment: Not that I know...but honestly you need to introspect what actually made to build this negative apprehension about you....Success or Failure are nothing but Situations driven through different state of minds, promise yourself,,,,impossible is nothing ;)

Comment: constant failures at the interviews made me think I am a loser, not that I born this way.

Comment: Take a small break, give your brain time to forget this negative state and then try again.....till then trying more would just keep sinking you deeper in the pit.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to write down your positive attributes. Also fix your view of yourself. Every one has something to bring to the table.

That includes you

Comment: my friends thinks I am an amusing guy, and I get many calls during weekends to hang out, though I am not sure if that helps if I state that in a company interview, which is a serious thing, and I do not want to seem not serious.

Comment: "Fix your view of yourself" might be hard to do alone. A couple suggestions on how might help. For example "I'm not good at sports", but are you there to cheer on and uplift someone who has a goal? And enlisting the help of your firends (and writing down what they say!) will help for a change in point of view.

Answer (score 4):

**No one is objectively defined as a loser.** Its your mentality, however, I wouldn't hire.

> My succinct response was: "only if you like losers", which ended the interview quickly.

This just tells me you give up before you've even got to the difficult bit. You haven't been tested and you're trying to get out of getting hired. Perhaps you don't even want a job.

> I grow up as a loser, no success at any sports, not good with girls, overweight with a BMI of 28, dropped out of college, my questions keep getting negative scores in this website. I am just curious, have you ever hired a loser guy or not, if so why did you hire?

Completely depends what you're being hired for but unless you're being hired to play sports, flirt or be a model those don't matter.

Dropping out of college can happen for a lot of reasons and your questions on this site aren't a measure of how well you would do in a job.

The thing that comes out of your question, however, is a self-pitying attitude that prevents you from trying. Positive attitudes don't give people some magical success, just the will to try.

When I'm hiring I look for someone who will give something their best, what you best is will change as time goes on but your attitude is key.

Comment: Great answer, though the tone is maybe a little bit judgemental. A positive attitude can be really hard to achieve at some points in life. @DenisSmith you don't have to work on this alone, there are a lot of options of professional help for that, find a therapist who will help you work through your self-esteem issues. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is twofold. One is you come into the interview with a imposter syndrome that should you succeed, it means you failed. Two is that nobody likes a downer. A job isn't a measurement of success, but rather a tool to succeed in whatever it is you want to do. Be it being a loser or doing something else.